# Maximum current vs temperature

Tags: current, temperature

I am using a 24V - 175A generator and I would like to use 37 meters of wire for my charging circuit. The voltage drop need to be less than 2V.

I did some calculations with the American Wire Gauge table:

**For AWG 4/0 (0000):**
R = 0.16072 Ohms/Km
Length = 37 meter
R = 0.16072/1000*37 = 0.00595 Ohms
Voltage drop = 175 * 0.00595 = 1.04V
Power = 175^2 * R = 175 * 175 * 0.00595 = 182 W

**For AWG 2/0:**
R = 0.16072 Ohms/Km
Length = 37 meter
R = 0.255512/1000*37 = 0.009454 Ohms
Voltage drop = 175 * 0.009454 = 1.65V
P = 290 W

My question is: What will be the change of temperature of these wires? I don't want it to burn...

If you can explain (mathematically) the calculations of the temperature, I would be very happy.

Thanks!

Comment: You give the same electrical resistance per meter for 4/0 and 2/0 wire. That can't be right.

Comment: Why those specific lengths? And do you care about the change in temperature or do you really care that the wires are within specification?

Answer (score 2):

The exact temperature rise depends on the thermal resistance from the wire to ambient, which we don't know.  This depends on insulation type, thickness, and whether the air is moving or not.

However, looking at the dissipation per meter or per foot will give you a conceptual feel.  If that's low enough, you don't have to do the formal calculation.  You say your first cable has a resistance of 161 µΩ/m (I'm using your figures without checking them).  At 175 A, that is a dissipation of 4.9 watts/meter, or 1.5 watts/foot, or 125 mW/inch.

Imagine a one inch length of wire in front of you.  125 mW sounds like it would get barely warm for such a decent size chunk of copper.  To put this in persective, you can have a SOT-23 package on a PC board dissipate about that much safely.  The one inch chunk of cable will be much bigger.  At this low level of dissipation per length, you are going to be quite safe and further detailed calculations aren't worth the effort.

However, if you really wanted to calculate the temperature rise, you'd somehow have to come up with the thermal resistance of the cable to ambient.  That would be specified in units like °C per watt per meter of cable.  Multiply that by your 4.9 W/m value, and you get the temperature rise of the cable above ambient.

Comment: @ThePhoton: Looks like I copied some numbers from the question incorrectly, fixing now.

Comment: I get ~4.9W per metre for 0000 AWG (11.68mm diameter) MiscEl reports a max of 230A for a PVC covered copper cable of this gauge.

Comment: Removed my earlier comments -- no longer relevant after editing.